# Apache Error - Installing PHP 5.5.7 in Apache 2.2 on Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I've downloaded and installed PHP 5.5.7 (VC11 x86 Thread Safe) from http://windows.php.net/download/.

Followed instructions from http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php & http://www.reaper-x.com/2007/09/24/installing-and-setting-up-apache-22-series-with-php-5-on-windows/ to no avail.

Apache simply will not start with the added PHP configuration in httpd.conf...if I comment out all PHP configuration Apache starts with no issues.

[image: Apache & PHP Configuration]

**EDIT**

[image: Updated php.ini to forward slashes]

Updated php.ini to forward slashes

Comment: What version of Apache2 are you running? If you are running any version below 2.4, this is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Delete and uninstall everything you have done so far.**

Download apache from apache longue `http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/binaries/httpd-2.4.7-win64-VC11.zip`
Ectract to c:/apache24

Download module modules-2.4-win64-VC11.zip
    http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/modules/modules-2.4-win64-VC11.zip

Extrct and copy `mod_fcgid.so` into `apache24\modules`

Open command prompt AS ADMINISTRATOR

`cd\ c:\Apache24\bin` to the folder with the httpd.exe file in it

type: `httpd -k install` 
type: `net start apache2.4`

Should be running provided no errors.

Download php from windows.php.net extract files to `Apache24\php`

Delete `php.ini-production`
Rename `php.ini-development` to `php.ini`

In `php.ini`:

Uncomment line 731: `extension_dir = "ext"`

Uncomment the follownig lines: (873 ...):

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

In `httpd.conf` in line 218 uncomment the following line and edit to : `ServerName localhost`

Change line 58 `Listen 80` to change server port

In `httpd.conf` include this line.:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

in the end of httpd.conf add the following lines:

```
<IfModule fcgid_module> 
   FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:\\Apache24\\php" 
   FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:\\Apache24\\php;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;" 
   FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:\\Windows" 
   FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:" 
   FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP" 
   FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP" 
   FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:\\WINDOWS" 
   FcgidIOTimeout 40 
   FcgidConnectTimeout 10 
   FcgidMaxProcesses 8 
   FcgidOutputBufferSize 64 
   ProcessLifeTime 0 
   FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 0 
   FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0 
   FcgidMaxProcesses 50 
   FcgidFixPathinfo 1 
   FcgidZombieScanInterval 20 
   FcgidMaxRequestLen 536870912 
   FcgidIOTimeout 120 

  <Files ~ "\.php$"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI 
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php 
    FcgidWrapper "C:/Apache24/php/php-cgi.exe" .php 
  </Files>

  <IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

In line 276 add  index.php near index.html

Enable `htacess`

un-comment: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
Replace all "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All". (find and replace all)